# command line tidy for HTML that does not insert HTML global structures like <!DOCTYPE>, <body>

Tags: html, parsing, unix, html-parsing, tidy

I'm using [this html5-tidy program](https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5) to pipe debug output from a web app to display to the console so that as a developer, a debug dump of a string variable containing HTML will not be an awful blob of text but rather a somewhat structured view of the HTML.

This is basically to extend upon what I have already done using `perltidy` for inspecting perl data structures: The string outputted from Data::Dumper is sent through `perltidy` to make it easier for a human to analyze. Because Dumper will only ever produce syntactically valid Perl, this works pretty well.

Until we get to the big blobs of HTML text variables.

So I'd like to do the same with text (intelligently insert whitespace and newlines), but `tidy` is doing too much work for me:

```
$ ../bin/tidy -q test_tidy.html 2>/dev/null | diff test_tidy.html -
1,6c1,17
< <!-- COMMENT --> <p>This example shows how Tidy can indent output while preserving formatting of particular elements.</p><pre>This is <em>genuine preformatted</em> text</pre> <!-- END -->
---
> <!-- COMMENT -->
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
> <head>
> <meta name="generator" content=
> "HTML Tidy for HTML5 (experimental) for Linux https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5/tree/c63cc39">
> <title></title>
> </head>
> <body>
> <p>This example shows how Tidy can indent output while preserving
> formatting of particular elements.</p>
> <pre>
> This is <em>genuine preformatted</em> text
> </pre>
> <!-- END -->
> </body>
> </html>
```

Theoretically I can make assumptions about how `tidy` is going to "always" add those extraneous things, and basically extract them back out, or something. But that's horrible for many reasons. First, if I go in and take that stuff out, then if it so happens that the input has it in there correctly or partially correct, it will get changed by `tidy` to be more correct than the original input was, which is bad! I can potentially display both copies so that there is no strange ambiguity in using the tool. But I'd like to avoid this and somehow have the `tidy` just do tidying of these HTML pieces, instead of trying to build a standalone HTML page.

However I am basically really close to what I want, so I'd rather not try to make something from scratch because I know it will be difficult and error-prone. Tidy also automatically sends over STDERR a really nice collection of warnings and errors (which I suppressed in the example above) which are also superb for placing alongside the debug functionality because while we have a good automated code checking standard in place for processing perl, the generated HTML is not subject to any sort of scrutiny.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you shouldn't even be using html tidy.  It makes for bad coding practices.  But you can, however, validate your code.  This should make things a little more tidy.

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Sure, but hitting a (restful or not) web service from a debugging script is not very practical. maybe as part of some deployment/build process this can be done, but it's not like i'm gonna happily go and copy+paste my code out of Dreamweaver or something into that web-form. I gotta have something better than that. Besides, my script would fail whenever *their* servers are down? Not good enough!

Comment: Validation is a one-time thing that merely checks whether your HTML and CSS is complaint to industry standards.  I was merely suggesting that you validate your code to make sure your errors are not being caused by simple syntax errors. Oh, and by the way, you can validate by file upload.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I do remember using validator sites where you just give them the URL of your own site, and they validate it for you. That's really neat. But is totally not what I'm asking for in this question.

Comment: I was merely suggesting that you validate in case your errors are caused by a simple syntax error.  I did not mean to suggest validation as a cure-all.